# Upon creating a cpShape does it also create a body for the shape?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am using cocos2d and chipmunk in my game and I am wondering if by creating a cpShape like so:

```
cpShape *helmet_1 = [game.spaceManager addCircleAt:cpv(245, 102) mass:STATIC_MASS radius:20];
```

is there also a body created for the shape?

Answer (score 1):

In this case yes, since you are using SpaceManager:
http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-spacemanager/source/browse/trunk/src/SpaceManager.mm#731

Regular Chipmunk keeps them separate to give you more flexibility at the cost of a little more complexity.

Comment: So if I use the combineShapes method from spacemanager will that free the seperate bodies and make just one body for all the shapes?